# What does "to be around for something" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In this sentence :

> I wasn't around for all of that.

Does "around" mean "aware" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in that sentence, it means "I was not present during those events."

[AHD "around" adj (3)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=around)
3. Being in evidence; present: *asked if the store manager was around.*

Comment: Note that *in evidence* is an idiom meaning "clearly visible" (the figurative meaning, "present", is what's pertinent here nonetheless).